# Rendering problem when created navigation drawer activity in android studio

Tags: android

These are the errors
1)Render problem
Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme   Tip: Try to refresh the layout.

2)Missing styles
Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?
Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.

3)Failed to instantiate one or more classes
The following classes could not be instantiated:
  - android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
  - android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.

If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.

Exception Details

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener
```

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.devkumar.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

MY MAIN.XML FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

values\styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
  <item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item>
</style>
```

Comment: it is showing Cannot resolve symbol '@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout'

Comment: add this `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'`